# How to store values from input fields when using onchange in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, onchange, input-field

I'm trying to access values in each input fields and multiply width by height, then display it.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Here is my code.

```js
const width = document.querySelector("#width");
const height = document.querySelector("#height");
const demo1 = document.getElementById("demo");
const demo2 = document.getElementById("demo1");

width.onchange = function() {
  let num1 = Number(width.value);
  console.log(num1);
  demo1.innerHTML = num1;
};

height.onchange = function() {
  let num2 = Number(height.value);
  demo2.innerHTML = num2;
  console.log(num2);
};
```

```html
<label for="width">Width (mm)*</label>
<input required class="width" id="width" type="number">
               
<label for="length">Height (mm)*</label>
<input required class="length" id="height" type="number">

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of things you could do in that situation. You could just go ahead and get the value from the other input and that's it.

```
width.onchange = function() {
  let num2 = Number(height.value);
  let num1 = Number(width.value);
  
  demo2.innerHTML = num2 * num1;
};

height.onchange = function() {
  let num2 = Number(height.value);
  let num1 = Number(width.value);
  
  demo2.innerHTML = num2 * num1;
};
```

as you can see is the same code, so you could create a function for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values in an ***object*** using a `change` eventListener for each input, one for ***width***, the other for ***height***. Run the same *call back* that will check the `event.target`'s ***classList*** for **width** and **height** as you have them assigned in the HTML.

Once we find a `classList` that ***contains*** one, we assign the key value of the event: ***width*** ***or*** ***height*** as the key, then we push the `event.target.value` as the **value** of the **object** => `obj['width'] = parseInt(e.target.value)`.

Then we check `Object.keys(obj).includes("width") && Object.keys(obj).includes("height")`, so we have a key that matches both ***width*** and ***height*** in the object set as a key, then we sum the values.

```js
const width = document.querySelector("#width");
const height = document.querySelector("#height");
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");

const obj = {}

function multSum(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('width')) {
    obj['width'] = parseInt(e.target.value)
    demo.textContent = `${obj.width}`
  }
  
  if (e.target.classList.contains('height')) {
    obj['height'] = parseInt(e.target.value)
    demo.textContent = `${obj.height}`
  } 
    
  Object.keys(obj).includes("width") && Object.keys(obj).includes("height") ?
    demo.textContent = `${obj.width} * ${obj.height} = ${obj.width * obj.height}` : null;
}

width.addEventListener('change', multSum)
height.addEventListener('change', multSum)
```

```html
<label for="width">Width (mm)*</label>
<input required class="width" id="width" type="number">

<label for="length">Height (mm)*</label>
<input required class="height" id="height" type="number">

<p id="demo"></p>
```